# Unable to set background resource on a Button

Tags: android, android-view, android-button, android-resources

I have an application on which I apply some resources to buttons to modify their backgrounds.

All work well, but when my application goes to onResume after onPause, I'm not able to set the background anymore.

I have a set of 18 buttons, and when I am in onResume, i call:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    Button b = l.get(i);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
}
```

In l i have the list of all buttons got from `findViewById()`.

This works only for the last element of the for, but not for the others.

Any idea?

** Edit **

This is the code I use for populating the array

```
btn_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
l.add(btn_1);
```

this is repeated for all my buttons.

** Second edit **

```
public void onResume() {
    btn_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
    l = new ArrayList<Button>();
    l.add(btn_1);
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        Button b = l.get(i);
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
    }
}
```

The same is done in `onCreate()`.

Comment: can you post the code you are using to populate the array.

Comment: do u find any error or warnings ??

Comment: We're gonna need to see more of your code to make a determination. Looks like your doing something wrong else where. Also, how do you calculate `max`? Why not use `l.size()` instead?

Comment: please post the code of your onCreate and onResume methods,

Comment: if he said that the last element is affected, so the value of max i guess is correct, i think that there is something wrong in methods onCreate() and onResume() , so he should add the code of those methods in order to better understand the problem :)

Comment: Because I don't need to color till the last element, but till the user is arrived, so this is max.

Comment: I'll post the code ASAP. Thank you

Comment: And, by the way, no error or warnings.

Comment: I don't understand what you were trying to convey. Can you please clarify that sentence?

Comment: I have 18 buttons, but I don't need to color all of them. Max is defined by the user, and I need to color from 1 to max buttons.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm tracking. The issue is happening some place other then that code. Please post your onCreate(), onResume(), and the method in which you set max.  Btw, are you sure your activity isn't going to onDestroy()?

Comment: Posted onCreate and onResume.

Comment: What is the feature that you are trying to implement with this code?

Comment: Logging all the related values will give you a fair idea where its going wrong.. Update the findings here..

Comment: Can you show me the `...` code? I know it might be long but show us a couple of buttons not only one. and tell me plz when you do I think the problem is there

Comment: userSeven7s: I'm trying to get the buttons colored after onResume.

Comment: Sherif elKhatib: the `...` code is the same for btn_1, just swap btn_1 with btn_2, btn_3 and so on.

Comment: are you having this issue on a Activity or a Fragment?

Answer (score 5):

try the d following.. this will works fine.

```
List<Button> mButtonList = new ArrayList<Button>();

onCreate() {

    mButtonList.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1));
    mButtonList.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2));
    mButtonList.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3));
    ....

    for(Button b : mButtonList) {
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}


onResume() {
    for(Button b : mButtonList) {
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple example:

**Activity**

```
public class StackOverFlowActivity extends Activity {   
    private ArrayList<Button> myArray = new ArrayList<Button>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myArray.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1));
        myArray.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2));
        myArray.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_3));
        myArray.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_4));
        myArray.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_5));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        for (Button b : myArray) {
            b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        }
    }
}
```

**XML main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My color in the Strings.xml**

```
<color name="blue">#0099CC</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    Button b = l.get(i);
    b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
}
```

If max is really big you might want to cache the `getColor` result before the loop.

EDIT:

According to the docs: [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) is to be used with drawable ids only, and [setBackgroundColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) seems to be exactly what you need, so maybe another part of your code isn't working well, maybe the loop, the above line for `setBackgroundColor` works well on my app.

Answer (score 1):

You've said:

> ": the ... code is the same for btn_1, just swap btn_1 with btn_2, btn_3 and so on. "

if so, than these lines are resetting your Array every time you try and add a new button.

```
l = new ArrayList<Button>();
l.add(btn_1);
```

P.S. you should avoid using a manual creation of buttons array - instead use some Parenting Layout such as LinearLayout and then fetch his button son's using getChildAt(i), **It's much cleaner**. Example:

```
    // Register all the buttons in the layout to the OnClickListener
    LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_buttons);
    int childcount = lin.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
        View v = lin.getChildAt(i);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: In this case, he would have outofbounds exception in his for loop because his ArrayList would only have 1 element. (Unless max != 1) But he said he is not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.getChildCount(); i++) 
{
    Button b = (Button) l.getChildAt(i);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. its working for me

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            btn_title[i] = new Button(ActivityName.this);
            btn_title[i].setText(menu.menu_title[i]);
            btn_title[i].setId(i);
            btn_title[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btn_title[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(dataxml
                    .getMenucolor()));
            btn_title[i]
                    .setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(dataxml.getFontsize()));
            btn_title[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                    | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            btn_title[i].setSingleLine();
            btn_title[i].setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);

            btn_title[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonListner());

        }
```

hope this will help

Comment: This doesn't work, and it is significantly different from what I asked.

Comment: have u tried setBackgroundColor instead of backgroundResource?

Answer (score 0):

why don't extend Button class, set its color, then use that new class?

Answer (score -1):

It wont work obviously , let me explain why it has set last value of button . 
you are using of one button reference  (whatever u got from `(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1)` )
and untimely there is a one button reference and u just change its value using  `l.add(btn_1);`

what you need to do is , **do create a new button instance** for each button and **inflate** it in proper view .

here is the small tick for that

```
for (int i==0 ; i < length; i++ ){
    Button button  = new Button(context); 

    collectionOfButton.add(button) ;
}
```

use that buttons collection using **inflate** if u try to integrate in some **xml layout** file .

Comment: I already use other instances of buttons, like btn_2, btn_3 and so on.

Comment: create instance with difference reference ..don't use (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1) )  to make button object

Comment: @dhams this is not true, as we can use findViewById() for as many view components we want, as long as the ID's passed are present in the layout xml file

Comment: @sunil :NO sunil its not you can't create may buttons using that reference like findViewById() . u have make new every time for each button . u don't trust me then  try to create a multiple dynamic button  using one reference of findViewById() , it won't allow you . (it will create only one button )

Comment: @dhams here in this case, the original poster creates buttons separately from different ID's as `Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);` and `Button btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);` and so on... so, here he will get separate objects of `btn1` and `btn2`

Comment: @sunil uhh.. no need of long process ..just make make button in for loop like for(int i==0; i<length; i++){Button b  = new Button(context);}
any way try with your approach you will understand all the that .

Comment: @dhams ok... your approach will work if he is creating 'Button' array dynamically via program. but in this case, the author is inflating layout XML files and getting the view objects using `findViewById(int)`

Comment: @sunil It means you didn't understand question properly . please look again what his problem !!